# what are drawbacks of PNN over MLP

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification, probability

I have a question that i couldn't find any straight forward answer for it anywhere.
it seems that **PNN** is much faster than **MLP** at least in training process and it is more accurate too. so why MLP is **still being used** for classification tasks instead of PNN?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an intuition of how these two works. Let's take an example of a binary classification using PNN and MLP. For PNN, you can have only 1 hidden layer where number of nodes is always equal to the number of training data. And We don't have to learn the weights but we have to learn the kernel parameters in the hidden nodes. The weight between a node representing class 1 in this layer and the hidden layer is set to 1 if those nodes belong to class 1 and 0 otherwise. If we assume all the neurons are the same there will be only 1 parameter to learn and therefore its training is much faster than MLP. 
For MLP, we can have many layers as we want, usually developers use only 1 hidden layer but google use up to 11 layers for their house number recognition. That might be the one possible reason for using MLP over PNN.